# Wpf InkCanvas save stokes as svg

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, inkcanvas

Is it possible to save InkCanvas stroke collection to svg image? Only thing I can find is that I can save the strokes as GIF with embedded ISF (Ink Serialized Format) or maybe render them as bitmap. I want to save strokes in vector format that can be interoperable with other platforms (like web).

Comment: Not sure how the question is too broad? I am asking a very specific question; no offence but the person who voted for it to be closed because it's too broad should reread the question.

Comment: Maybe add how you would save them as GIF. Then asking for the svg one wouldn't too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here are the steps

1. Iterate over the `StrokeCollection`
2. Get `PathGeometry` of each `Stroke` by calling `GetGeometry` function and then calling `GetOutlinedPathGeometry`.
3. Get `Figures` out of `Geometry`. I am doing it by saving the `PathGeometry` to XAML and then parsing the `Figures` attribute by `XElement.Parse`.
4. Then I can just create a svg document and add each path (see code below).

I am using [SVG Rendering Library](https://svg.codeplex.com/) to create SVG document.

```
var svg = new SvgDocument();
var colorServer = new SvgColourServer(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

var group = new SvgGroup {Fill = colorServer, Stroke = colorServer};
svg.Children.Add(group);

  foreach (var stroke in InkCanvas.Strokes)
  {
      var geometry = stroke.GetGeometry(stroke.DrawingAttributes).GetOutlinedPath‌​Geometry();

      var s = XamlWriter.Save(geometry);

      if (s.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
      {
          var element = XElement.Parse(s);

          var data = element.Attribute("Figures")?.Value;

          if (data.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
          {
              group.Children.Add(new SvgPath
              {
                  PathData = SvgPathBuilder.Parse(data),
                  Fill = colorServer,
                  Stroke = colorServer
               });
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: Very useful!

I suggest changing the first line in the `foreach` loop to the following:

`var geometry = stroke.GetGeometry(stroke.DrawingAttributes).GetOutlinedPathGeometry();`

This will ensure that if the strokes are created with different tools/attributes, they will be preserved. For example, if someone uses a square shaped nib instead of a round.

EDIT: Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DaxPandhi have you tried the edits? Just making sure that it works with your edits. If so then please confirm and I'll approve the edits. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have successfully used the modified code in my own application and it works well. I first tried the original code you had pasted, and while it worked, my different nib shapes were not stored. After modifying, I was able to preserve the shapes.