# Save UWP Ink Strokes as SVG

Tags: svg, uwp, inkcanvas

Is there a way to save InkStrokes from an UWP InkCanvas as SVG?

I already save them in the format 'GifWithEmbeddedIsf', this is good for reloading the ink data in another InkCanvas, but my problem is when I use the Gif to display the Ink Strokes inside a web client. This Gif does not have the same quality as displaying the InkStrokes in the UWP app [this is especially visible while zooming in].

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261548/wpf-inkcanvas-save-stokes-as-svg) answer that's available in WPF apps, but the same API is not available in UWP [or I haven't found it].