# Convert byte array into svg document in .net core

Tags: c#, svg

I want to convert byte array into SVG document in .net core 2.0 . The very first thing i did is looked for  the .net Core 2.0 library Which i didn't found then i implemented a class library in net framework targeting 4.6 as it is already there.[Conversion of byte array into svg document in .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261548/wpf-inkcanvas-save-stokes-as-svg) .And when i am trying to use this framework library it is throwing run time error like PresenationCore assembly not found. So is there any way to do it in net core?

Comment: Saying you have a "byte array" isn't really helpful. What is the format of those bytes?

Comment: @DavidG memory stream

Comment: Yes, but what is in there? SVG isn't a byte array structure, it's basically XML.

Comment: @DavidG we are fetching data from mongodb and possibly its in JSON

Comment: "possibly" is no use to us at all!

Comment: @DavidG its in JOSN

Comment: OK, what is the format of the JSON? SVG cannot be represented in JSON so this makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidG this is the binary which is taken from pen device object